# Couldn't match expected type `[([Char], a0)]' with actual type `([Char], t0)' Haskell

Tags: haskell, char, int, ghci

I am starting to program with haskell. The program I am developing just sums the total of a list with two elementes, for example:

```
[("book",10),("cookies",2),("icecream",5)]
```

This should return "17". Here i my code:

```
total [] = []
total ([("c",e)]:y) = total y ++ [e]
```

But while running in GHCi it gives me this error:

```
<interactive>:80:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `[([Char], a0)]'
                with actual type `([Char], t0)'
    In the expression: ("livro", 10)
    In the first argument of `total', namely
      `[("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]'
    In the expression:
      total [("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]

<interactive>:80:21:
    Couldn't match expected type `[([Char], a0)]'
                with actual type `([Char], t1)'
    In the expression: ("bolachas", 2)
    In the first argument of `total', namely
      `[("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]'
    In the expression:
      total [("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]

<interactive>:80:36:
    Couldn't match expected type `[([Char], a0)]'
                with actual type `([Char], t2)'
    In the expression: ("gelado", 5)
    In the first argument of `total', namely
      `[("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]'
    In the expression:
      total [("livro", 10), ("bolachas", 2), ("gelado", 5)]
```

This is probably very simple but as a beginner I was not able to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line:

```
total ([("c",e)]:y) = total y ++ [e]
```

the `([("c",e)]:y)` does not do what you want.  It matches a nonempty list in which the first element is also a list (because of the `[...]`) and in which that sublist has exactly one element, which is a pair whose first element equals `"c"`.  In order to match what you want, you need to write:

```
total ((c,e):y) = total y ++ [e]
```

However, this still won't do what you want, as it constructs a list of all of the `e` values in the input list.  To sum them together, you need to do:

```
total [] = 0
total ((c,e):y) = total y + e
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @jwodder said, note that there's also another way to approach the problem. Instead of thinking /how/ you would compute the desired value, think about /what/ you do: you take the second element of every list item and then sum those elements up.

So you could start by writing two functions, one which takes a list of tuples yielding a list of all the second elements, and another computing the sum of a given list of numbers. A good start is to come up with the type signatures but defining the functions to evaluate to `undefined`:

```
-- Takes a list of tuples and returns all the second elements
getSecondElements :: [(String, Int)] -> [Int]
getSecondElements someList = undefined

-- Computes the sum of a given list of integers
sumOfIntList :: [Int] -> Int
sumOfIntList someInts = undefined
```

Using these, defining you function is straightforward:

```
total myList = sumOfIntList (getSecondElements myList)
```

You can run this through ghci and it'll type-check, which is a good sign. When you try to actually use `total`, you get an error though because the other two functions are just `undefined`.

Before you go and think about how to implement them, it's a good idea to see whether they exist already. You can search [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for type signatures and it'll dig up functions matching that signature. The signature of `getSecondElements` doesn't yield any hits but the signature for the second yields a lot of hits, and most of those hits don't even talk about `Int` at all: Hoogle is smart enough to understand that functions which deal on arbitrary types of lists (say: `length` or `head`) may also be applicable. If you scroll down the page you'll see that there's an existing `sum` function already!

For the first function, you can repeat the process (recursively, if you like): in order to get all second-tuple-elements in a list, you first need a function which gets the second element of a tuple, like

```
getSecondElement :: (String, Int) -> Int
getSecondElement = undefined
```

and another function which applies that to all elements of a list. I'll skip ahead a bit: the standard function for getting the second element of a 2-tuple is called `snd`, and the function for collecting the results of calling a function on all elements of a list is called `map`. Try running

```
:t map snd
```

in ghci to see the type of `map snd`:

```
map snd :: [(a, b)] -> [b]
```

...which is a generalized version of the type of our `getSecondElements` function! So the two missing pieces are `map snd` and `sum`, which gives:

```
-- Takes a list of tuples and returns all the second elements
getSecondElements :: [(String, Int)] -> [Int]
getSecondElements someList = map snd someList

 -- Computes the sum of a given list of integers
sumOfIntList :: [Int] -> Int
sumOfIntList someInts = sum
```

Instead of having two extra functions, you can also define `total` in terms of `map snd` and `sum` directly:

```
total someList = sum (map snd someList)
```

...which can be shortened to

```
total = sum . map snd
```

Not bad, is it?